# Errors with the Basic OpenCV Hello World

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm simply trying to run the basic openCV hello world tutorial code, but I'm getting errors. I have everything properly linked and built, but it's not working.

This seems like it should be extremely easy, but it's not working. OpenCV is properly installed, and I even attempted to place opencv_core220d and opencv_highgui220d in the Debug folder of my project, but no luck.

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 under Windows 7 64bit.

Here's the errors:

```
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Webcam test\Debug\opencv_core220d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Webcam test\Debug\opencv_highgui220d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avifil32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvfw32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avicap32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Webcam test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The program '[5512] Webcam test.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Here's my code:

```
// OpenCV_Helloworld.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
// Created for build/install tutorial, Microsoft Visual Studio and OpenCV 2.2.0

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Open the file.
    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("photo.jpg");
    if (!img) {
        printf("Error: Couldn't open the image file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Display the image.
    cvNamedWindow("Image:", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Image:", img);

    // Wait for the user to press a key in the GUI window.
    cvWaitKey(0);

    // Free the resources.
    cvDestroyWindow("Image:");
    cvReleaseImage(&img);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        printf("Error: Could");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does it die when you step through it with the debugger?

Comment: Wait, nevermind. Looks like they're not errors but warnings. Still makes me want to fix the problems though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, they're warnings not errors. The program works as expected.